# How do I install PySpeech for Python 3?

Tags: python, windows, installation, text-to-speech

So far I've downloaded and installed distribute and pywin32, however I don't understand how to install PySpeech itself. The directions say to " browse to the folder that you extracted pyspeech-0.5.2.zip to and run the following in the command prompt: 
'/python32/python speech.py install' or 'python speech.py install'".

I extracted pyspeech to the desktop and tried both of the above commands in the command prompt. This did not work as I got the following error: "'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." Obviously I'm missing something. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to remedy the situation?

I suspect the issue lies in the "browse to the folder that you extracted..." portion of the directions, as I don't know how that ties into the process. Moreover, forgive my naivete because I've never installed something via command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `python` to your `PATH` environment variable. See [here](http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html#configuring-python) for instructions, and then you will need to run `python.exe setup.py install` or whatever (note the `.exe`).

Comment: *Feels inept*... So I went to the instruction page you provided, and got things working until my attempt to find the .exe. I'm absolutely terrible with the command prompt. Would you mind explaining it as if I was a child?

Comment: That's OK :). [This](https://openhatch.org/wiki/Boston_Python_Workshop_3/Friday/Windows_set_up_Python) is a good elaboration, see if you can get through that instead.

Comment: I got the install working in the command prompt (cd Destop, dir...), however I have one final problem. I cannot import speech. I I can't import speech because I don't have the speech module. It should come with the base package (which I have), however it does not support python 3.2. So, with that out of the way, what can I do to work around this? Note: I don't want to downgrade to python 2.5

Comment: Well, obviously you can't use it on a version on which it doesn't support :). Either downgrade to a version of Python 2, or port it so it supports Python 3. It looks like a small module, so doing the porting shouldn't be too hard. Also, if my answer helped you get this far please accept it to mark it as the solution.

Comment: You got it. I was just waiting until I got a definitive solution. Thanks!